# Visual Studio Code behind Proxy Failed to Load jsconfig.json from Schema Store

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

Created a jsconfig.json to define a JavaScript project within Visual Studio Code. Once open the containing folder with VS Code, VS code raises a problem:

> Problems loading reference
>   'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/jsconfig.json':
>   Request vscode/content failed unexpectedly without providing any
>   details.

This is probably caused by corporate ntlm proxy server. However, it is possible to get the content of this json schema file by Chrome browser after copying the URL into Chrome's address bar. By documentation, VS Code should get much of the networking support available in Google Chrome. Please point a direction with regard to further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Extension may be the cause.

In my case, it occurred with prettier.
After running 'npm audit', I reviewed the eslint and prettier settings and fixed them.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you edit your answer to include how you fixed them?